# Copying an image via dd results sometimes in unbootable disk

Tags: debian, dd, grub2

I have the following setup of completely identical devices (Model and Revision are matching):

- Device A: OS fully installed, all required software installed.
- Device B: blank* disk
- Device C: blank* disk

* on all devices is (in case of A was) an Ubuntu version installed which I don't want to use as I have a complete, customized Debian I want to use

So I took an image of device A and disk-dumped it onto the disk of device B. After that I compare the crc32 of the image and device B's memory, they match. I boot B, it works like a complete clone of A.

Now I disk-dump the same image on the device C (which is completely identical to A and B) and compare their crc32 values again, another match. I boot it up and it says "No bootable medium found".

Why is this happening, the dump process worked without problems as the crc32 confirms. But why doesn't it work? And much more interesting: How do I fix this problem?

**Edit**

Output of `fdisk -l` (all devices are named like mmcblk0pX)

```
Device  Start     End       Sectors   Size
p1            34     97656     97623  47.7M  EFI System
p2         97657   2690217   2592561   1.2G  Microsoft basic data
p3       2691072  13025279  10334208     5G  Linux file system
p4      13025280  14940159   1914880   935M  Linux swap
```

Comment: dd does not stand for "disk dump" providing the exact string run and the result returned would be more use.

Comment: Are you trying to boot with them all plugged in? How are they connected (usb, sata, esata, scsi)? Have you reconfigured the bootloader on Xdc to target it's own disk? Does your platform support booting from the third disk? Did you mark the drive/partition as bootable?

Comment: I have not found a full name in `man dd` and thought disk-dump would make sense ;)

The HDD of the devices are in fact build in memory chips (I'm using the Intel Compute Sticks). For the copy-process I boot from a live USB stick, which I remove before booting from internal memory. Gparted says, that the boot flag is set on the first partition (fat32, 512MB)

As command I used `sudo dd if=image.img of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=4M` in the directory `image.img` is located. It returns without any errors and says "1824+0 records in, 1824+0 records out, 7.7GB copied" And a bit more detailed numbers.

Comment: Which suggests to me the error is in not being able to boot past the second "device" or (historically more likely) 4th partition.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand that or I was unclear about my device description. A, B and C are physically separate devices. I just copied the image again, now I have the following partitions on my disk (each name starts with mmcblk0) p1 (fat16, 47MiB, boot and esp flag set),  p2 (fat32, 1.24 GiB, msftdata flag) p3 (ext4, 4.93 GiB, no flags) p4 (linux-swap, 935 MiB, no flags) and 1 MiB unallocated. Sorry for the confusion with the 512MB fat32 partition of the previous comment, I tried to install a "clean" debian yesterday which left this partition, it was not bootable either.

Comment: `fdisk -l` your env, as you are trying to boot it.

Comment: `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0` on live usb says

Device-Start-End-Sectors-Size#

p1 - 34 - 97656 - 97623 - 47.7M - EFI System#
p2 - 97657 - 2690217 - 2592561 - 1.2G - Microsoft basic data#
p3 - 2691072 - 13025279 - 10334208 - 5G - Linux file system#
p4 - 13025280 - 14940159 - 1914880 - 935M - Linux swap#

Comment: No device. Just `fdisk -l` It wil be clearer if you edit your original question rather than adding it in comment

Comment: You are right, the formatting in the comments is ridiculous compared to the question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I did not find the reason. But I found a workaround which is ok for me. I started the EFI shell and entered fs0 with `fs0:` The EFI shell now prompts something like `fs0\ >` via `cd EFI` and `cd debian` I was able to find a file named `grubx64.efi`. I ran the file by entering `grubx64.efi` and it started the system, showed me GRUB2 where I could select my debian install. It boots completely normal and with `sudo grub-install` and `sudo update-grub` I was able to restore the somehow broken EFI record. After a reboot the device C behaves exactly like device B and A.